# Two column lookup in table array using INDEX and MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I would like excel to display the value from table array which has two matching cells `com_cd` and `div_cd` using `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

I have tried the following formula but it did not work.

```
=INDEX(K9:K53,MATCH(K3,I9:I53,0),MATCH(K4,J9:J53,0))
```

Here is a screenshot of the excel sheet with the desired result given according to `com_cd` and `div_cd`

[image: div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an array formula `(CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)` instead of `Enter`.

```
=INDEX(K9:K53,MATCH(K3&K4,I9:I53&J9:J53,0),1)
```

Not tested but should work.

Will edit later explaining our formula and reason why your formula doesn't work.

Comment: thanks man now its working.sure please explain your formula later.

Answer (score 1):

Your *column_num* parameter on the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) cannot sinply provide a secondary row criteria. You need a way to ensure a two column match on the *row_num* parameter and leave the *column_num* either blank or as **1** (there is only only column in `K9:K53`).

The standard formula for K5 should be,

```
=index(K9:K53, aggregate(15, 6, row(1:45)/((i9:i53=k3)*(j9:j53=k4)), 1))
```

... or,

```
=index(K9:K53, min(index(row(1:45)+((i9:i53<>k3)+(j9:j53<>k4))*1e99, , )))
```

The cell range K9:K53 has a total of 45 rows. The position within K9:K53 will be within `ROW(1:45)`. The first formula forces any non-matching row into an `#DIV/0!` error state and the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) uses option **6** to ignore errors while retrieving the smallest valid entry with the [SMALL sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) (e.g. **15**). The second formula performs the same action by adding 1E+99 (a *1* followed by 99 zeroes) to any non-matching row and taking the smallest matching row with the [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7).

[image: AGGREGATE two column match]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: As it stands, should the number of rows being referenced change (a not unlikely scenario), then the OP would have to redetermine to what the portion ROW(1:45) should become. If you pass K:K to INDEX, as opposed to K9:K53, then the ROW portion is simply ROW(K9:K53). And, in general, if the range is Range1, then the ROW portion is ROW(Range1), thus offering a simple and constant relationship between the two, without any further thought or manual amendments required should Range1 change.