# searching excel table with multiple criteria, returning multiple results

Tags: excel-formula

i have got a large table (1500 lines) with product information. this contains of codes in column A, and descriptions in column B.

i need to be able to search the descriptions by multiple criteria, for example one description string might contain the words "red" and "small" and then return all the codes that match this.

can anybody help here?

What I need to extra from:

[image: this is extract of my list]

What I hope to achieve:

[image: this is what i want results]

Comment: adding a snippet of data that you are working with is always a good idea.  It does not have to be the same was what you are working with, but enough to illustrate what you are trying to do.  Also it can be very good to show what you are looking for as an end result.  Finally, a lot of people will want to know what you have tried so far.  [See how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two column lookup in table array using INDEX and MATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010190/two-column-lookup-in-table-array-using-index-and-match)

Comment: @jeeped Yes very similar,  different though in that the OP will need to so a string search to see if "red" is par of "Ladies black pumps size 4" or "Men's Red Soccer Cleats", but I have seen that as well somewhere in another post.

Comment: have added some pictures to explain what i have and what results i want

Comment: Being on the sarcastic side here briefly before I start playing with an answer.  So to technically answer your question, "YES, someone is capable of helping you" 8)  Its going to take me a bit to retype your data

Comment: thanks forward Ed very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula below will do a two word search.  If you need more words to search on repeat this part of the formula and adjust the search cell as required:

```
1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1,($B$1:$B$11))))
```

If you want blank cells instead of NOT FOUND, use "" instead of "NOT FOUND"

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1,($B$1:$B$11))))*1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2,($B$1:$B$11))))*ROW($B$1:$B$11),ROW(A1))),"Not Found")
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of concept]