# Search table based on 2 criteria and manipulate and add entries to a new column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of data to which I would like to add comments based on older versions of the list which is another worksheet in the same workbook.
[image]

Now I tried an approach with two loops (the first one actually looking if there was a comment in a given row and then the second looking for the criterias in every row of the new sheet and adding a comment if necessary) but it turned out way too slow. There are around 15 000 entries in each sheet and around 6500 entries with comments in the older sheets.

I need a faster way for getting the comments from the old sheet to the new sheet. As you can see, certain combinations of criterias in the older sheets might have multiple corresponding combinations in a newer sheet. In that case, I need the comment in ALL rows that fit the criteria.

Comment: Why not a simple formula? See [Two column lookup in table array using INDEX and MATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010190/two-column-lookup-in-table-array-using-index-and-match).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object to identify the a unique list of the first two columns while collecting a list of the comments IDs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyCommentIDs()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, aCOMs As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim d As Long, dCOMs As Object

    Set dCOMs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dCOMs.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("Sheet19")
        'collect data from Old Sheet into an array
        aCOMs = .Range(.Cells(3, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    'build dictionary; collect comment IDs
    For a = LBound(aCOMs, 1) To UBound(aCOMs, 1)
        'if there a comment ID?
        If CBool(Len(Trim(aCOMs(a, 3)))) Then
            'concatenate/deliminate the first two columns
            k = Join(Array(aCOMs(a, 1), aCOMs(a, 2)), ChrW(8203))
            'does it exist in the dictionary?
            If dCOMs.exists(k) Then
                'it exists; concatenate the comment id onto the dict. key's item
                dCOMs.Item(k) = Join(Array(dCOMs.Item(k), aCOMs(a, 3)), ", ")
            Else
                'does not exist; add a new dict key/item pair
                dCOMs.Item(k) = aCOMs(a, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next a

    With Worksheets("Sheet19")
        'return the dictionay items to the new sheet
        For b = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'concatenate/deliminate the first two columns
            k = Join(Array(.Cells(b, "A").Value2, .Cells(b, "B").Value2), ChrW(8203))
            'does it exist in the dictionary?
            If dCOMs.exists(k) Then
                'transfer the comment id
                .Cells(b, "C") = dCOMs.Item(k)
            End If
        Next b
    End With

    'clean up
    Erase aCOMs
    dCOMs.RemoveAll: Set dCOMs = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]