# Excel Index & Match two columns while pulling data for a third

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula which compares numerical values of two columns and when a match is found return data from a different column.

Here is the problem I am having - the formula I have come up with seems to go Row by Row - for example, if column A & B are the two columns I want to compare, with column C having the data I want if a match is made.  If I have a value of 1 in row A1 and a value of 1 in B1 - it will successfuly return the data in column C.

The problem is that my numbers are jumping, the row's do not match, for example column A is 1,2,3 however column B is 1,3,2.  The end result here is that I get data for the value 1, but on the mismatch for the second row I get no value.

Basically the formula I made seems to do a hard comparison based just off the two rows of each column - meaning it will only compare A1 to B1.  What I really need is it to compare the ENTIRE column and disregard the rows completely

Here is the formula I have been fooling around with - this formula works if A1 and B1 match

=INDEX(M:M,MATCH($L:L,$V:V,0))

In this formula M has the data I need, while columns L and V have numerical values, I need it to not 'hard check' row by row and instead evaluate the entire column and when a match is found return the result (so if both columns have a '2' return that value REGARDLESS of the fact that the '2' may be in rows A2 and B9)

Hopefully I explained my issue well, and I appreciate all the help I can get

*EDIT*

Sorry for failing to explain it properly on my end -- I will base my explanation off the picture link below.

I need data from column B to show up in column D.  What is happening is row 2 matches so the data is successfully retrieved for number 1 - however on row 3 where column A switches the numbering it compared the number '3' to the number '2' and recognizes it is not a match and returns NA -- even though there IS a match in columns A4 and C2 -- in this situation for C3 I would need the data from B4 to showup in D3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrKJp.png

Comment: Then compare only one at a time.  in the first row put `INDEX(M:M,MATCH(L1,V:V,0))` and copy down.

Comment: Is this relevant to your situation? [Two column lookup in table array using INDEX and MATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010190/two-column-lookup-in-table-array-using-index-and-match)

Comment: The issue is I don't want it to compare one at a time - almost every row has a different value than the other.  What ends up happening is lets say '2' is in A1 and B:3 - it evaluates A1 says there is no match, does the same for A2, and A3.  So even through '2' is in A1 and B3 (I need the data from a third column at that point) it says there is no match What I need it to do is MATCH based off the data in the column cells as they are all mixed up and do not match by the rows   ----   So if it finds a '2' in columns A and B - regardless of the row - pull the data in the column next to it from A

Comment: this is very confusing. at one [point you said to match column b and get the value from c that is in that row and at the very next instance you say the same with column A.  Which is it.  Do you want to find A1 in Column B and return the matching value in C at the row in B or do you want to return C1?  Or reverse it where you are trying to find B1 in Column A and return C where the match was found in A or return C1?  There are four possible return combinations.  Please put some test data and expected outcome in the original post using edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two formulas that will each give you the return you want, Put one of the following in D2 and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

OR

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: The second one worked - thank you so much, that's awesome! Thanks again Scott, and my apologies for the confusion originally.

Comment: @ant187 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.